# How can I dynamically create multi-tiered trees?

Tags: apex, lightning

I want to create a tree whose hierarchy number changes according to the data given.
How can we dynamically increase the hierarchy instead of preparing many hierarchies in advance?

In my code, I can create a tree only for the prepared hierarchy.

```
    public class items {  
        @AuraEnabled  
        public string label { get; set; }  
        @AuraEnabled  
        public string name { get; set; }  
        @AuraEnabled  
        public Boolean expanded { get; set; }  
        @AuraEnabled  
        public List<items> items { get; set; }  
        public items( String name, String label, Boolean expanded, List<items> items) {  
            this.label = label;  
            this.name = name;  
            this.expanded = expanded;  
            this.items = items;   
        }  
    }
```

```
    Account TopAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentCD__c,ChildCD__c FROM Account WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'];
    items Top = new items();
    List<items> First = new List<items>();
    for(Account FirstLayer : [SELECT Id, Name, ParentCD__c,ChildCD__c FROM Account WHERE ParentCD__c =: TopAccount.ChildCD__c]){
        List<items> Second = new List<items>();
            for(Account SecondLayer : [SELECT Id, Name, ParentCD__c,ChildCD__c FROM Account WHERE ParentCD__c =: FirstLayer.ChildCD__c]){
                List<items> SecondValue = new List<items>{new items(SecondLayer.Id ,SecondLayer.Name , true, null )};
                    Second.addAll(SecondValue);  
            }
            List<items> FirstValue = new List<items>{new items(FirstLayer.Id ,FirstLayer.Name , true, Second )};
                    First.addAll(SecondValue);  
        }
    Top.name = TopAccount.Id;
    Top.label = TopAccount.Name;
    Top.expanded =true ;
    Top.items = First;
```

Comment: Hi Kawasaki, welcome to stack. Please provide details like what are you trying to achieve. What problem are you facing, etc and any screenshots and code would help

Comment: @salesforcesas I want to display in the tree following the parent-child relationship that exists in the record. In my code, I can create a tree only for the prepared hierarchy. I want to create multiple layers dynamically.